# Wifi Tethering error on Pi 3 OSMC

Tags: wifi, ssh, linux, pi-3, osmc

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with the latest OSMC installed.

It's connected to LAN using the ethernet port.

I tried to enable WIFI tethering from the ethernet to Hotspot,

But it gives me this error "Error enabling hotspot check logs",

I don't know how to check logs but I search about this issue in google.

I have found the command 'connmanctl tether wifi on' I did it on SSH and it says permission denied even with sudo.

EDIT: I also re-flashed the image file of the OSMC, same results.
What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem was that the wifi adapter no enabled and the GUI didb't detect that and let the option to enable tethering.
So simply by enabling wifi adapter it worked